# $\omega$-limit set of an ODE is just one point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider the system
$$x'(t) = y(t)$$
$$y'(t) = -y(t)^3-p(x(t)),$$
where $p(x(t))$ is a polynomial of odd degree whose leading coefficient is positive. I'm interested in proving that the $\omega$-limit set of the trajectory $(x(t),y(t))$ consists of exactly one point. I'm not sure where to start. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As usual, it would be good to add some context to explain *why* you are interested in proving this. Is is some conjecture of your own arising in some other context (where?), a problem from some book (which book?), a homework assignment in a course (in connection with what topic?), and so on. Anyway, are you familiar with **LaSalle's invariance principle**? If I'm not mistaken, you could use that with $V(x,y)=P(x) + \tfrac12 y^2$, where $P(x)=\int_0^x p(\xi) d\xi$.